# NSNumber from CGFloat

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, nsnumber, cgfloat

Is there a safe way to "convert" a `CGFloat` to a `NSNumber` ?

`NSNumber` has the `numberWithFloat:` and `numberWithDouble:` methods but `CGFloat` being defined as `float` or `double` depending on the platform, it seems risky to use either one of them.

Or is `numberWithDouble:` safe to use with a `CGFloat`, as it is the one with the more precision ?

Comment: If you have a enough high compiler version, just write *@(myNumber)* and it will be resolved at compile time. However you can safely call *[NSNumber numberWithDouble: myNumber]*, if *CGFloat* is defined to be double you do it correctly, it *CGFloat* is defined to be float you still haven't lost any precision.

Comment: safe? can you explain?

Comment: safe as "without precision loss". Is this why I was downvoted ?

Comment: I down voted it because IMHO you are just over thinking. C is full of functions that handle doubles, not overridden to work also with floats just because if you pass a float instead of a double **nothing harmful can happen**. It will just be implicitly casted to a double, which uses extra precision.

Comment: I'm over thinking it because my code will handle real money. So better be safe (pun not intended) than sorry. (and I also don't think this was worth a downvote, but eh...)

Comment: This casting wastes cycles, and can be significant in code that does lots of floating point arithmetic. In terms of math functions, I recommend using `tgmath.h` and letting the compiler choose the right function for you at compile time.

Comment: If you're handling money, you may wish to consider using a fixed point or decimal representation. See `NSDecimal` and `NSDecimalNumber`.

Comment: For which device support you are bulding this app?

Comment: Don't use floating point for real money.

Comment: @LithuT.V iPad but I didn't want it to be relevant, I wanted portable-ish code.
@ipmcc already using these, but wanted a convenient way to init them from `CGFloat`.

Comment: well iphone is a 32 bit device .CGFloat is a regular float on 32-bit systems and a double on 64-bit systems.thats why i asked

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I believe `@` `NSNumber` literal is good enough

```
@(myCGFloat)
```

Read more here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Comment: Thanks for the solution and the link. This was enlightening :)

Answer (score 24):

This is how I handled it:

```
@interface NSNumber (CGFloatAdditions)

+ (NSNumber*)numberWithCGFloat: (CGFloat)value;
- (CGFloat)CGFloatValue;

@end

@implementation NSNumber (CGFloatAdditions)

+ (NSNumber*)numberWithCGFloat: (CGFloat)value
{
#if CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE
    return [NSNumber numberWithDouble: (double)value];
#else
    return [NSNumber numberWithFloat: value];
#endif
}

- (CGFloat)CGFloatValue
{
#if CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE
    return [self doubleValue];
#else
    return [self floatValue];
#endif
}


@end
```

`CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE` is defined in `CGBase.h` conditionally by platform.

Comment: This is not even necessary, it's over-coding. If you call *[NSNumber numberWithDouble: value]* (for compiler versions that don't support literal numbers) you don't risk to lose any precision whether if the number is float or double.

Comment: Yes, but you waste cycles to convert between float and double on platforms where CGFloat is a float.  But whatever. Use this, don't use this. I wrote it a long time ago and I continue to use it. It works for me.

Comment: Thnaks @ipmcc, I'll use Lukas' solution but yours is what I was searching for originally.

Comment: I find it odd this is not NSNumber already, since they did add methods for NSInteger.